# How to get ID of current page in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3

I'm using TYPO3 v8, how can I get the id of the current page that I'm editing in the backend?

Comment: In what context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get current `PageId` like this.

in Controller file.

```
$currentPid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id
```

Using Typoscript.

```
temp.page_uid = TEXT
temp.page_uid.field = uid
```

Comment: I tried this "$currentPid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id"  and it didn't work ! I like to get the id of the current page in backoffice inside an extension that I have created and I don't have any controllers

Comment: The question specifically asked "in the backend". $GLOBALS['TSFE'] is instantiated in the frondend.

Answer (score 7):

Example: In your controller:

```
$id = (int)\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('id');
```

Comment: Just a hint: _GP('id') is only set when you have chosen a page in the page tree. Therefore, be aware of empty values - or zero when cast to integer as above.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on context, examples:

- If you are extending FormEngine (editing records), the parent page record is in the data array, prepared by some rather early data provider.
- If you are adding a feature to the 'info' module, the page id is a GET parameter, you should be able to access this in your controller.